# Angular 7 on refresh getting gateway timeout

Tags: angular, angular7, url-routing, angular-universal

Im facing problem in angular 7 with universal in my app, on this page (https://machinesrentals.com/category/working-at-heights), it will not open directly if you go to homepage (https://machinesrentals.com/) from top menu go to category working at height it will open normally but if you refresh the page it will break, on any other page is is fine
server.ts

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
import {ngExpressEngine} from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import {provideModuleMap} from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';
import * as express from 'express';
import {join} from 'path';
enableProdMode();
export const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4200;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/browser');
const domino = require('domino');
const fs = require('fs');
const template = fs.readFileSync(join(DIST_FOLDER , 'index.html')).toString();
const win = domino.createWindow(template);
global['window'] = win;
global['DOMTokenList'] = win.DOMTokenList;
global['Node'] = win.Node;
global['Text'] = win.Text;
global['HTMLElement'] = win.HTMLElement;
global['navigator'] = win.navigator;
global['Event'] = win.Event;
global['Event']['prototype'] = win.Event.prototype;
Object.defineProperty(win.document.body.style, 'transform', {
    value: () => {
        return {
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true
        };
    },
});
global['document'] = win.document;
global['CSS'] = null;
const {AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP} = require('./dist/server/main');
app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
}));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', DIST_FOLDER);
app.get('*.*', express.static(DIST_FOLDER, {
  maxAge: '1y'
}));
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { req });
});
```

app.server.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerModule, ServerTransferStateModule } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';    
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppModule,
    ServerModule,
    ServerTransferStateModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppServerModule { }
```

Search component

```
export class SearchResultGroupComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  constructor(@Inject(WINDOW) public window: Window,
    public formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    public appSRV: AppService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    @Inject(APP_BASE_HREF) private baseHref: string,
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object,
    private pagerSRV: PagerService,
    private productSRV: ProductService,
    private cartSRV: CartService,
    private categorySRV: CategoryService,
    public helperSRV: HelpersService,
    private headerSRV: HeaderService,
    public langSRV: LanguageService,
    public titleSRV: Title,
    public translate: TranslateService,
    private toastr: NotificationService,
    public dialog: MatDialog,
    private _renderer2: Renderer2,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document

  ) {
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') !== -1 || navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Trident/') > -1) {
      this.isIELimitApplied = true;
      this.generateRND = 12234354354;
    } else {
      this.generateRND = Math.floor(Math.random() * 90000) + 10000;
    }
    // console.log(this.currentLang)
    this.currentLangWithSlash = this.helperSRV.checkDefaultLang(this.currentLang);
    // console.log(this.currentLangWithSlash)
    this.setAndGetIsLoggedIn();

    this.currentUrl = this.router.url;
    this.helperSRV.setLocalStorage('srh_search_url', this.router.url);

    this.baseUrl = baseHref + 'assets/';
    //if (window.innerWidth > this.maxResolution) this.isSideBar = false;
    translate.get('searchResult.pageTitle').subscribe((res: string) => {
      titleSRV.setTitle('Rentaga - ' + res);
    });
  }
  setAndGetIsLoggedIn() {
    this.headerSRV.setIsLoggedIn(this.appSRV.loggedIn('search'));
    this.headerSRV.isLoggedIn.subscribe(updatedName => {
      this._isLoggedIn = updatedName || false;
    });
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.catNameURI = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('catname') || '0';
    this.subCatNameURI = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('subcatname') || '0';
    let apislug = this.subCatNameURI;

    if (this.subCatNameURI === '0') {
      apislug = this.catNameURI;
    }
    console.log("ngAfterViewInit", this.catNameURI, this.subCatNameURI, apislug);

    this.helperSRV.getMetaData(apislug, this.currentLang).subscribe(rs => {
      const seoData = rs.data || null;
      this.catDesc = seoData.catDescription;
      this.catImg = seoData.ogImage;
      this.helperSRV.settingSEoData(seoData, this.currentLang);
    }, err => {

    });
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.helperSRV.setLocalStorage('currentPage', '');
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.helperSRV.setLocalStorage('currentPage', '');
    //$(document).foundation();
    this.dropdownSettings = {
      singleSelection: false,
      idField: 'id',
      textField: 'name',
      selectAllText: 'Select All',
      unSelectAllText: 'UnSelect All',
      //itemsShowLimit: 3,
      allowSearchFilter: true
    };
    this.onResize();
    this.createForm();
    this.resetingSubCat();
    this.onChangesInForm();
    const latlong = this.helperSRV.getLocalStorage('srh_latLong').toString() || '0';
    if (latlong !== '0') {
      const splitedLatLong = latlong.toString().split(',');
      this.selectedLat = splitedLatLong[0];
      this.selectedLong = splitedLatLong[1];
    }
    this.catNameURI = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('catname') || '0';
    this.subCatNameURI = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('subcatname') || '0';
    if (this.catNameURI !== undefined) {
      // console.log(this.route.snapshot.data.seo.data);
      // this.helperSRV.settingSEoData(this.route.snapshot.data.seo.data, this.currentLang)
      this.IsCategorySearch = true;
      this.getCategories();

    } else {
      this.IsCategorySearch = false;
      this.gettingParams();
    }

    this.setRefineSearchErro();

  }
  getSearchResult(criteria, params) {
    this.load = false;
    this.response = this.productSRV.searchProductGroup(criteria).pipe(
      // side effect
      tap(success => {
        if (success.error.length !== 0) {
          this.toastr.showToaster(success.error[0], 'Error!', true);
          //alert('d');
        } else {
          this.searchResults = [];
          this.searchResults = success.data;
          let productsJson = [];
          success.data.forEach((row, ind) => {
            const catSlug = this.helperSRV.getLangConversionByIndex(row.productSearchResults[0].category, 'category_slug');
            const subcatSlug = this.helperSRV.getLangConversionByIndex(row.productSearchResults[0].category, 'parent_category_slug');
            const orgSlug = this.helperSRV.makeSlug(row.productSearchResults[0].organization_name);
            const productSlug = row.productSearchResults[0].slug;
            productsJson.push({
              '@type': 'ListItem',
              'position': ind + 1,
              'url': `https://rentaga.com/product/${catSlug}/${subcatSlug}/${orgSlug}/${productSlug}`
            })
          })
          this.productsJsonLD = {
            '@context': 'http://schema.org',
            '@type': 'ItemList',
            'itemListElement': productsJson
          };
          this.setJsonLd(this.productsJsonLD);
          //console.log(this.productsJsonLD)
          //this.window.scroll(0, 0)
          //rs.resultsCount = 200;
          this.totalItems = success.resultsCount;
          this.totalPages = Math.ceil(this.totalItems / this.pageSize);
          //this.pages = this.setPages(this.totalPages, this.currentPage);
          this.pages = this.pagination(this.currentPage, this.totalPages);
          //console.log(this.pagination(this.currentPage, this.totalPages));
          //if (!this.IsCategorySearch) {
          //this.createForm();
          //console.log(rs);
          this.filterCategories = [];
          this.langfilterCategories = [];
          if (success.filteredCategories.length > 0) {
            const newFilteredCat = this.helperSRV.getLangConversionByIndex2(success.filteredCategories, 'values');
            const newFilteredCatEN = this.helperSRV.getLangConversionByIndex2ReturnEn(success.filteredCategories, 'values');

            if (newFilteredCat.length > 0) {
              this.filterCategories = newFilteredCatEN;
              this.langfilterCategories = newFilteredCat;
              this.updateFilter();
            }
            let manufacturers__ = '';
            let keywords__ = '';

            this.filterCategories.forEach(element => {
              // console.log(element)
              if (element.name === 'Manufacturer') {
                manufacturers__ = element.selected_value.join(',');
              }
              keywords__ += element.name + ',';

            });
            // console.log(manufacturers__, keywords__)
          }
          // console.log(this.langfilterCategories);
          this.isFacetsAvailable = true;
          this.langfilterCategories.filter(lfc => {
            if (!lfc.minMaxEqual) {
              this.isFacetsAvailable = false;
            }
          })

          this.setFormValues(params);
          if (this.window.innerWidth <= this.maxResolution) {
            if (!this.isSideBar) this.toggleSideBar();
          }
          //}
          this.setClasses(); // setting bydefault list
          this.setPage(this.currentPage);
          this.load = true;
          this.isClicked = false;
          // console.log(this.form.value)
        }
      }),

      // mapping result to the array we need
      tap(console.log),
      map(success => success.data),

      // catching error
      catchError(error => {
        this.setFormValues(params);

        // if (error.error.error.length > 0)
        //   this.toastr.showToaster(error.error.error[0], 'Error!', true);
        // else
        //   this.toastr.showToaster(error.error.message, 'Error!', true);

        this.load = true;

        console.log('ERROR!', error);
        // console.log('Error!', error);
        throw error;
      }),
    );
  }
  async getCategories() {
    await this.categorySRV.gets().subscribe(rs => {
      if (rs.error.length !== 0) {
        //console.log(rs.error);
      } else {
        this.categories = [];
        this.categories = rs.data;
        this.getCatIdByCatSlug(this.catNameURI, this.subCatNameURI);
        this.gettingParams();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Search component html

```
        <ng-container *ngIf="response | async as searchResults;">
          <ng-container *ngIf="load && searchResults?.length > 0">
                <div class="column" *ngFor="let search of searchResults; let h = index">
                 </div>
        </ng-container>

        </ng-container>
```

Also not getting page source i need to wait for api

```
const latlong = this.helperSRV.getLocalStorage('srh_latLong').toString() || '0';
```

some time works fine when i removed `.toString()`
also getting translation variable in pagesource, Thanks in advance if you pls help me

Comment: I just tried and it does work

Comment: yes as i mentioned sometime does work, and page source issue is there dont see search result pagesource

Comment: Check your logs server side

Comment: `*ngIf="response | async as searchResults;"` im using this why it is not waiting for api response?

Comment: server side logs

`169|machin | ERROR ReferenceError: google is not defined
169|machin |     at GooglePlaceDirective.module.exports.GooglePlaceDirective.isGoogleLibExists (/home/nodejs/rental-customer/angular/dist/server.js:371767:9)
169|machin |     at GooglePlaceDirective.module.exports.GooglePlaceDirective.initialize (/home/nodejs/rental-customer/angular/dist/server.js:371774:19)
`